# Java selenium path

Tags: java, linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium

I am using the Selenium API, but I got the error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;`

Expected location of Chrome is

/`usr/bin/google-chrome`

but in my computer it is in
`/usr/bin/google-chrome`

I'm using Ubuntu, how I can fix this issue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have not downloaded, external chrome driver file for ubuntu. You should download chrome driver file ubuntu from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/). WebDriver API will not work with your already installed chrome browser like [Firefox or Safari Browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953865/why-there-is-no-need-of-external-firefox-driver-like-ie-and-chrome-in-selenium2)

After you have downloaded, You can either include the `ChromeDriver` location in your `PATH` environment variable or specify its location via the system property. Here is the link to get started with [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).

Answer (score 3):

After downloading the chrome driver from here -
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/

you will have to add following lines to your code

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();